# Free-running application under test exits shortly after I attach with VS2010 SP1 in x86

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, c++-cli

On Windows 7 x64, when I attach in x86 mode to a fairly complex free-running app, it runs for a while, then reproducibly exits.

```
MyApp.exe Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
```

followed immediately by

```
MyApp.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Sometimes if it runs OK, it would hit my breakpoint, I'll inspect the state, but when I hit F5 to keep going, the app exits in the same fashion.

Quick search for the error code tells me that it's a Stack Buffer Overrun.  I hear that it might be caused by incorrect unmanaged interop code.

I can run from debugger OK (F5), but free-running and attaching always has this problem.

Any thoughts on how I could narrow it down?

EDIT:  Here's a callstack i am seeing on a different machine (Windows Server 2008 R2 x64) here, might be related:

> clr.dll!__crt_debugger_hook()
>       clr.dll!___report_gsfailure()  + 0xeb bytes 
>       clr.dll!_DoJITFailFast@0()  + 0x8 bytes 
>       clr.dll!CrawlFrame::SetCurGSCookie()  + 0x2e9c4f bytes
>       clr.dll!StackFrameIterator::Init()  + 0x60 bytes
>       clr.dll!Thread::StackWalkFramesEx()  + 0x8a bytes
>       clr.dll!Thread::StackWalkFrames()  + 0x87 bytes 
>       clr.dll!CNameSpace::GcScanRoots()  + 0xd7 bytes 
>       clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::mark_phase()  + 0xae bytes
>       clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::gc1()  + 0x7b bytes
>       clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::garbage_collect()  + 0x1c1 bytes
>       clr.dll!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration()  + 0xba bytes
>       clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::try_allocate_more_space()  + 0x1cd0 bytes 
>       clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::allocate_more_space()  + 0x13 bytes
>       clr.dll!WKS::GCHeap::Alloc()  + 0x507 bytes 
>       clr.dll!Alloc()  + 0x5a bytes
>       clr.dll!SlowAllocateString()  + 0x41 bytes
>       clr.dll!UnframedAllocateString()  + 0x11 bytes
>       clr.dll!StringObject::NewString()  + 0x26 bytes 
>       clr.dll!Int64ToDecStr()  + 0x12e bytes
>       clr.dll!COMNumber::FormatInt64()  + 0x17e bytes 
>       mscorlib.ni.dll!6c60b8e1()
>       [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for mscorlib.ni.dll]

**EDIT2**  Things seem fine on x64 build of the app, issue only appears in x86.

Comment: You might find more information in your OS Event Viewer?

Comment: @Jason Williams: nothing in the event viewer.  Good try

Comment: Any access over UNC paths or to protected locations in the code? does running as a privileged user negate the problem?

Comment: @Mike Miller: running on a dev box, full privileges, local access only.  From the error code, it sounds like something is trashing my stack.  Prolly bad P/Invoke somewhere.

Comment: good luck and please update with results as I'm now more interested than when Bouncer had his own episode in Neighbours (Bouncers Dream) - that rocked.

Comment: I am able to inspect state by taking a ProcDump of a running process that has hit an assertion, then opening the full memory dump in Visual Studio 2010 SP1.  I still cannot continue from a breakpoint or from an assertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Windows SDK ntstatus.h header file:

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN
//
// MessageText:
//
// The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun 
// could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.
//
#define STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN      ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000409L)    // winnt
```

A buffer overrun on a stack allocated buffer is an infamous virus injection vector.  Microsoft got very serious about eliminating that potential thread in their code.  The C and C++ languages were first.  Managed code straggled behind, this is not something that is supposed to happen in a managed execution environment.

Nevertheless, the version 4 CLR was built with the protection in place, unlike earlier CLR versions.  And it does its job, although it is exceedingly rare for it to happen.  I've seen a question about it only once before.

Solving this problem is going to be difficult, especially when you have no obvious lead to what unmanaged code in your application might be tripping this protection.  Best thing to do is to make a minimal repro and contact Microsoft Support to show them what is going wrong.  Finding out what trips it while working on getting the repro is a likely outcome.

Comment: Behavior seems different on different platforms.  I see GSCookie on Server 2008 R2 x64, but no such message on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it stated that C/C++ code is the likely culprit, and it actually was, in my case.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I should be able to narrow it down by injecting GC.Collect() calls in my code: garbage collection checks GSCookie among other things.

Broken link1: http://7388.info/index.php/article/studio/2010-10-17/354.html

Broken link2: http://www.pubsub.com/Investigating-a-GSCookie-Corruption_Windows-NET-Troubleshooting-PInvoke-5wbEHu80dzF,rZ5U5DaVJaE

Comment: I am currently running with Jinx, and unable to force the code path to fail.  I am still unable to attach to a free-running app, as it immediately exits.

Comment: In retrospect, I feel it's one of the unmanaged libraries that we were relying on.  Once it's compiled out, no more problem.

Comment: The link http://7388.info/index.php/article/studio/2010-10-17/354.html
in this post currently produces a site temporarily unavailable message
http://p3nlhclust404.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net/SharedContent/redirect_1.html

Comment: @SteveMylroie I looked at the way-back machine.  Nothing in the archives.

Comment: Despite both of these links now being broken, this comment helped me figure out a similar problem (indeed with a P/Invoke call). I was getting it whenever an exception was thrown, but forcing GC made it possible to pinpoint the actual bug. +1

Comment: Sorry about the links, glad it helped.  Unlike the universe, the internet is shrinking

Comment: I had a similar issue with a native external DLL, putting a GC.Collect before the crash occured fixed it.As a second solution, putting the interop code within a GC.TryStartNoGCRegion also fixed the issue.
It seems the GC can interact with unmanaged memory

Answer (score 1):

is the interop signature correct? try using http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120 to generate it and try again.

Comment: did I mention this is a very complex application?  We have 185 DllImport statements.

Comment: Yesterday I was removing layers of my app to see what component caused it. I found out that the issue is not with P/Invoke signature, but rather in a precompiled module written in managed C++, targeting .NET 4.0. When calling into Managed C++, there's no P/Invoke required. It just works. Or not, in my case