# DllImport does not show in intellisense

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

It is first time I am trying to use DllImort in C#. But it is not appearing in InteliSense. I have added

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

But it is not working again. Instead this **[DllImportAttribute]** is shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to use it?  The attribute is the correct way.

Comment: Always describe 'not working'.

Comment: Have a read of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Also, might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319650/is-there-a-tool-that-generates-p-invoke-signatures-for-arbitrary-unmanaged-dll

Comment: I was trying to use it at wrong place. It was problem

Comment: Everything is fine. By convention all attribute classes end with the word attribute, but this doesn't need to be written in the code as the pre-compiler will add the word attribute to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do nothing wrong. Use this attribute to define the managed signature for the method you want to import.

As Example

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = false, 
                CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string moduleName);
```

Look in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) for all possible parameter for `DllImport`

Comment: I found answer, but thank you for your time